# AMP amp-iframe communication

Tags: amp-html

Having an `amp-script` within `amp-iframe`, and I want to do communication from `script.js` to iframe page via `postMessage`, changing src URL, etc...

```
<amp-script src="//path/to/script.js">
  <div>TEXT HERE</div>

  <amp-iframe
      height="100"
      layout="fixed-height"
      sandbox="allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"
      allowfullscreen
      frameborder="0"
      src="//path/to/iframe.html">
  </amp-iframe>
</amp-script>
```

What will be correct way? Since `postMessage` doesn't work for me, changing URL via `amp-bind` doesn't work due to missed user interaction while update.

Idea is to read `<div>TEXT HERE</div>` and pass it to iframe somehow.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any solutions for this?